# What are good solutions for concurrency profiling in .NET?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, concurrency, profiling, profiler

Would you please name some .NET performance and memory profilers that are specially tuned for concurrency?

I am just aware of **[VS 2010](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/profiler/archive/2010/02/25/vs2010-profiler-guidance-rules-part-1.aspx)**'s built-in profiler.
Tools like **[dotTrace](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-performance-profiler/)** and **[ANTS](http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/)** are wonderful but as far as I know, they do not offer special solution for concurrent applications. Another interesting tool is **[PerfMonitor](http://bcl.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=PerfMonitor&referringTitle=Documentation)** but I am wondering whether a better tool is available or not?

Thanks beforehand.

Comment: Google ".NET concurrency analyzer".  They are not cheap, you'll have to do your own shopping.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of them listed here:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_performance_analysis_tools

The two you mentioned: JetBrains [dotTrace](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-performance-profiler/), and Redgate [ANTS](http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/), would definitely be at the top of my list.

IMHO...

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I meant solutions that are specially tuned for multi-threaded applications. As far as I know, these two do not provide such a feature.

Comment: I believe both do (along with MSVS, e.g. "VSPerfCmd /start:concurrency").  SUGGESTION: Please download evaluation copies (if you haven't already done so) and check.